# .htaccess redirect with wildcards?

Tags: .htaccess

I've got a weird but into my forum in which a URL of a page changes after 1 second, without redirecting the page.

I'll explain with an example:

When someone visits my forum and edit a post, let's say he get this URL:

`http://mywebsite.com/viewtopic.php?f=55&t=66&p=88#p88`

where p=88 is the post number in the database.

Now, after 1 second, this url is redirected for some bugs to:

`http://mywebsite.com/viewtopic.php#p88`

The page is not reloaded at all, just the URL changes.

If the user tries to reload the page, he will get an error message because the link:

`http://mywebsite.com/viewtopic.php#p88`

is of course wrong.

So I was thinking about a solution using .htaccess in order to redirect

`http://mywebsite.com/viewtopic.php?f=55&t=66&p=88#p88 (working URL)`

to

`http://mywebsite.com/viewtopic.php?f=55&t=66&p=88 (still working URL)`

which should fix my bug.

I tried with htaccess but it seems it's harder than I thought.

My guess is i need to redirect something like this:

`RedirectMatch 301 ^/viewtopic.php?f=.*$&t=.*$%p=.*S#p=.*$`

but I'm not able to do it since I don't know where to redirect this. Are you guys able to help me?

Thank you so much

Comment: Redirecting won’t “fix” the bug. You should rather analyze what the real reason of the problem is. If the URL changes without the page being reloaded, that most likely means it is a JavaScript using the HTML5 History API.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Should I start from trying to unloed each .js file one by one  to find the right one?